# Artikel bei Aufzählung

Tags: article, comma

Kann der Artikel bei Aufzählung von Nomen ausgelassen werden?

> Die Weiterentwicklung, die Wartung und die Integration der bestehenden Modelle 
>   durch eine zweite Person erfordert - je nach Fall - das Lernen eines neuen Framework und eine neue Programmiersprache.

also so:

> Weiterentwicklung, Wartung und Integration der bestehenden Modelle 
>   durch eine zweite Person erfordert - je nach Fall - das Lernen eines neuen Framework und eine neue Programmiersprache.

Comment: Kommt immer drauf an. Was ist der Kontext? ^^

Comment: Ist das eine Überschrift/ein Stichpunkt, oder Teil eines Satzes? Im letzteren Fall: wie soll der komplette Satz lauten?

Comment: Es handelt sich um ein Satz. Habe jetzt den ganzen Satz eingefügt.